# How to build a mobile responsive menu that will always have a 100% height and show all its list items

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a mobile responsive website. 
It has a nav menu button that opens .list div up - when clicking the menu button.
I inserted the div of the .list right after the nav bar.

When the menu opens it doesn't show all list items in my  tag. 
I have to give my main div .list different height sizes and I find it not so efficient.

I will paste my relevant code  part of the nav bar,  and the relevant CSS parts.

HTML:

```
<div class="list">
            <h2 id="cat-header"> ALL CATEGORIES</h2>
                <ul class="sports">

                        <li class="mainli">
                        </li>

                        <li class="mainli">
                        </li>

                        <li class="mainli"> 
                        </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sports{
    /*display: none;*/
    padding: 0 ;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
    /*height: 210%*/
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.list{
    width: 99.9%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
    /* top: 65%; */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
    height: 75%;
    display: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I created different width sizes that change the

```
.list{
    height: 75%;
}
```

in a way that it will fit, but I got to a point where a lot of small mobiles have the same width but different heights. I need something automatic with a 100% height.

This is a visual example of my problem:

[image]

and here is an good example of how it should look like. This is customized to a specific mobile.

[image]

Comment: Set the height to auto and see what happens.

Comment: prevents me from scrolling altough the overflow-y: auto; @JasonBassett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.list{
    width: 99.9%;
    /* top: 65%; */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: ..prevents me from scrolling altough the overflow-y: auto;

Comment: Remove `overflow-y:auto`..... and paste the exact code I provided into your CSS. Highlight all of the code in my answer... and replace your `.list` styles with my styles... @Hatul

Comment: Still the same.. Please view the 2 images 

http://oi61.tinypic.com/15dtc9k.jpg
and 
http://oi61.tinypic.com/1zp0dc5.jpg

Comment: Also remove that `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. You don't need it.

Comment: I need -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; for the flow of the scrolling, without it it's just sticky scrolling. 
with or without, I get the same problem

Comment: Give me the url where this page is, or send me all of your code. @Hatul